# Why do fall through Switch cases compile in c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, fall-through

As we all know switch cases in c# do not allow you to fall through according the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx)

> Execution of the statement list in the selected switch section begins with the first statement and proceeds through the statement list, typically until a jump statement, such as a break, goto case, return, or throw, is reached. At that point, control is transferred outside the switch statement or to another case label.
>
> Unlike C++, C# does not allow execution to continue from one switch
>   section to the next. The following code causes an error.

If thats the case why does this compile:

```
void Main()
{
    int  s = 3;
    switch (s)
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("hit 3");
            break;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't this be identified as a compile time error?

Comment: fall through *is* allowed, but only with empty case statements, like in this example. This shouldn't throw a runtime exception. This code is fine.

Comment: @Dennis_E - that's not fall thorough, but yes, it is valid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, the code you provided doesn't throw a run time error.  Secondly, it falls under a different category (from same MSDN article, emphasis mine):

> A switch statement can include any number of switch sections, and each
>   section **can have one or more case labels** (as shown in the string case
>   labels example below). However, no two case labels may contain the
>   same constant value.

The difference is whether you have multiple empty `case` statements, that's allowed.  But you can't have a `case` with code in it, and let it fall through.

Comment: This is more obvious in VB.Net, whose syntax is along the lines of `case 1,2,3,4:`